# Homologous cycles

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Prof. Haynes Miller's Lectures on Algebraic Topology, p.3, he said that two cycles that differ by a boundary is homologous. My question is what does he mean by "differ by a boundary"? I initially thought that they have different boundary but it doesn't make sense because my intuition for homologous cycles is that they are of same appearance.

Comment: This means that the algebraic difference two cycles, $c_1-c_2$, is a boundary.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about homology in the context of algebraic topology, I assume that you are either thinking about singular, or cellular homology. In either way, homology is a functor that associates to a chain complex

$$\longrightarrow C_n\longrightarrow C_{n-1}\longrightarrow... \longrightarrow C_1\longrightarrow C_0\longrightarrow 0$$

a set of homology groups $H_n$ (without any maps between them).

A chain complex has a map between the chain groups called "the boundary map", $\partial_n: C_n \longrightarrow C_{n-1}$. A part of the definition of a chain complex requires that $\forall n: \partial_n\circ\partial_{n-1} = 0$. There is a reason why this is called the boundary map, and if you would be interested I could elaborate further.

Given a chain complex, you could compute its $n$'th homology group as follows

$$H_n := \text{Ker}\partial_n/\text{Im}\partial_{n+1}.$$

I hope this makes sense, basically the fact that $\partial^2 = 0$ implies that $\text{Im}\partial_{n+1}\subseteq \text{Ker}\partial_n$ as abelian groups, or as $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, if you are considering integral homology, so it makes sense to take such a quotient.

The definition I gave you is purely algebraic, and has no intuition or motivation behind it.

Some terminology: the group $\text{Ker}\partial_n\subseteq C_n$ is sometimes denoted $Z_n$, and is called the group of cycles. The group $\text{Im}\partial_{n+1}\subseteq \text{Ker}\partial_n\subseteq C_n$ is sometimes denoted $B_n$ and is called the group of boundaries.

In these notations, $H_n := Z_n/B_n$.

This means that given a cycle $\alpha\in Z_n$, $\alpha$ defines a homology class, given by its equivalence class modulo boundaries. Usually we denote this class by $[\alpha]\in H_n$. Two homology classes $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ are therefore equal, if they belong to the same equivalence class, i.e. if $\alpha - \beta \in B_n$, that is, if their difference is a boundary.

A more visually intuitive explanation of this topological picture, is that the group of boundaries, $B_n$, are boundaries of the $n+1$ dimensional chains, i.e. $C_{n+1}$, which one should think of as $n+1$-dimensional manifolds, and the group of cycles, $Z_n$, is the subgroup of $C_n$ of manifolds that have no boundary, like an $n$ dimensional sphere for example, or a cycle in dimension 1. Then two cycles, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are homologous, if there is some $n+1$ dimensional manifold (chain), whose boundary, taken with the right orientation, is $\alpha - \beta$.

I hope that helps, but keep in mind that there are plenty of other topology textbooks, which do a much better job at explaining this very basic concept together with accurate intuitions. I recommend you to take a look at either Hatcher's book or Fouchs and Fomenko, which is my personal favorite.

Comment: Hi. Your explanation was awesome. I'm aware why $\partial_{n}$ is called a "boundary map", but I'm not sure why, for the Abelian group $S_{n}(X)$ of singular $n$-chains in a topological space $X$, $\partial_{n} : S_{n}(X) \rightarrow S_{n-1}(X)$ is defined by $\partial_{n}(\sigma) := \sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^{i}d_{i}\sigma}$.

Comment: Thank you. I recommend asking this in a separate question (after you searched for an answer online and couldn't find one). The definition essentially coincides with what you should imagine to happen. Take a 1 dimensional singular simplex going from $\Delta_1$ to a line connecting the points $P$ and $Q$. What should be $\partial \Delta_1$? Is it $P + Q$, is it $P - Q$ or $Q - P$? Well, if you pick the first answer, then you would find that the circle, an object which has no boundary, all of a sudden has a boundary = WRONG ANSWER. So it could only make sense to set it to be $P - Q$ or $Q - P$ >>

Comment: and the specific one you choose is simply a matter of convention. If you have an $n$-dimensional singular simplex, then it also has a positive or negative orientation (multiply your chain by -1 to get the opposing orientation). Given an orientation on your $n$-dimensional simplex, you obtain an orientation on your boundary. The operators $d_i$ you specify usually send the simplex $\Delta_n$ to its $i$'th face, which is usually obtained by fixing one of the coordinates (the $i$'th one) to be equal to 0. This face usually comes with an orientation, but sometimes this orientation is different >>

Comment: than the orientation of the corresponding face as the boundary of our simplex. The basic example is the line $PQ$, which has boundary $P$ and $Q$, but one of the faces should be taken with a negative orientation in order to have the orientation coming from $PQ$. The alternating minus signs are aiming to exactly correct this problem. I suggest that you look at the case of a 2 and 3 dimensional simplices, take their boundaries, and see that the alternating signs come naturally when taking boundaries.

Comment: What is meant by $a-b$, is there an intuitive explanation for this because I cannot seem to wrap my head around it?

Answer (score 1):

Two cycles $a$, $b$ differ by a boundary if there is a chain $c$ such that $b-a = \partial c$, or equivalently, $b = a+\partial c$, where $\partial$ is the boundary operator.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much. It's really hard to study math with a bare fluency in English.